# Color limits from the HERE Map Image REST API

Tags: heatmap, here-api

We've signed up to the Pro plan and now we need to create a report using Map Image REST API to generate heatmaps using multiple colors (more than 4 colors).

I saw on the documentation that there is a limit of 4 levels and colors, I'm wondering if it's possible to use more colors in order to reach our requirements.

Do you have plans to increase the limits or beta version that doesn't have those limits?

For instance, we need to create 6 areas each one with different colors and 6 levels on the same map as shown on the following image, I should be able to use 6 different colors but only shows up 4 colors.

[Map image example with 6 areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loWXG.png)

Here is the request

```
GET https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/heat
    ?apiKey={{API_KEY}}
    # Area 1 - Yellow
    &a0=49.27,-123.48
    &rad0=1900
    &l0=0
    # Area 2 - Red
    &a1=49.25,-123.38
    &rad1=1500
    &l1=1
    # Area 3 - Blue
    &a2=49.18,-123.342144
    &rad2=1500
    &l2=2
    # Area 4 - Green
    &a3=49.28,-123.35
    &rad3=1000
    &l3=3
    # Area 5 - Orange
    &a4=49.21,-123.55
    &rad4=1800
    &l4=4
    # Area 6 - White
    &a5=49.30,-123.60
    &rad5=1000
    &l5=5
    #
    &z=11
    &w=900
    &h=900
    &plt=FCFF00,EB2501,001EFF,1FE80C,FF8C0D,FFFFFF
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to our plans for this API, I can, however, raise a ticket internally asking that this be considered. My guess is that it's for performance as well as "length of URL" concerns, but at minimum I can ask.